# Can't fetch data by "id" without map or filter methods in my Angular project

Tags: angular

I'm in the process of creating a simple to-do list app. On the front page I have 10 users (data from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users). Whenever you click on the user 'details', it should display another page and show the data based on the user id ( here is the data http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos). In my code, it displays the entire data instead of the specific user data. What can I do to solve this problem, without filtering or mapping the array?

Here is user-details.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './user-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-details.component.css']
})
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  userdetails: any[] = [];
  public userId;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

getUserDetails() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUserDetails().subscribe(
      (userdetails: any) => this.userdetails = userdetails
    );
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the reason not to use filter or map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are making a request to 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos' but if I understood correctly you want the full information to do list of the selected userId, that's simple just access the right http request example :

```
  export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  userdetails: any[] = [];
  public userId;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  getUserDetails() {
    return this.http.get(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId=' + this.userId
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.userId = params['id']; // retrive the selected user Id
    });
    this.getUserDetails().subscribe(
      (userdetails: any) => (this.userdetails = userdetails)
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: I edited my comment because I misunderstood the point, but passing the parameter userId in the request it will retrieve the user's to do list

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to receive the user ID passed into the public variable `userId`. For that you can modify your **user-details.component.ts** file as shown below.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userId=this.route.snapshot.params['id']
    this.getUserDetails().subscribe(
        (userdetails: any) => this.userdetails = userdetails
    );
}
```

Next in order to hide the data if `userId` of each object in array doesn't match the public variable, update the **user-details.component.html** file.

```
<tr *ngFor='let userdetail of userdetails' [hidden]="userdetail.userId!=userId">
    <th class="bg-primary">
        {{userdetail.completed}}
    </th>
</tr>
```